# Do commutation relations exist between superfields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, commutator, superspace-formalism

To quantize a theory, Klein gordon field for example, commutation relations are stablished. Or anticommuting ones in the fermionic case.

If I have the Wess.Zumino model or the free model:

$$S~=~\int\Phi\Phi^\dagger d^8z.$$

Can I obtain in some way relations (commutation or anticommutation, I don't know) like this:

$$[\Phi(z),\Phi^\dagger(z^\prime) ]~=~?$$

Comment: Well, without having any fancy insight my approach would be to plug in the expansions of the superfields in terms of component fields, impose canonical (anti)commutation relations on those and see what happens.